# Functions in JavaScript object prototype undefined when imported by another module

Tags: javascript, inheritance, es6-modules

I am setting up JS modules for a project, where I'm using prototypes to do OO programming (since I'm not sure the framework supports ES6 class syntax). One module contains "classes" for a specific purpose, and the other module imports and uses these.

I looked through all the documentation I could find on how to properly set up inheritance with JS prototypes and how to export and import modules. The below code example illustrates what I'm going for.

MyModule.js:

```
function A(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

A.prototype.foo = function(bla) {
    // ...
}

function B(x, y, z) {
    A.call(this, x, y);
    this.z = z;
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

export { B };
```

MainModule.js:

```
import * as MyModule from "./MyModule.js"

var b;

function bar() {
    b = new MyModule.B(1, 2, 3);

    b.foo(4); // <-- error happens here
}
```

When I try to run `bar`, `b.foo` is undefined. Member variables (e.g `b.z`) work fine, but functions added to the prototypes do not.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: works fine for me.  One note, though: you are exporting/importing using ES6 syntax so you'll need to change that to pre-ES6 syntax or compile the code with something like `Babel`.  (...and if you are compiling you might as well also use the nicer ES6 class syntax)

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors what's the easiest way to try and test this code? I tried online JS test apps but those can only do a single file

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors switching to ES6 class syntax did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out Qt (which is what I was using) prefers the ES6 class syntax to do what I was trying to make it do. Once I switched over to that, the import/export and inheritance and everything else worked. Thanks to everyone who commented, I can now mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're using es6 syntax so you could just do something like

```
export function B(x, y, z) {
    A.call(this, x, y);
    this.z = z;
}
```

then import

```
import { B as MyModule } from "./MyModule.js"
```

or whatever name you want to give it

Comment: Tried it, still getting the same problem.

Comment: are you using something like Babel to compile? if not then the es6 import syntax wont work no matter what

Comment: I'm actually using Qt (specifically QJSEngine), which claims to be compatible with ES6, though I'm starting to have my doubts. That said, properties like `b.z` are added without any trouble, so clearly something got called, but for some reason it does not add the functions from the prototype.